# How to match a width and height size with a Regex expression and use Sort By in SQL or C# to build a drop-down?

Tags: c#, sql, regex, sorting

I've a SQL query which will retrieve the following table, but I want to order the Board size correctly in Descending order (Small to Large) in a drop-down selection. I'm using *C#* to build the *Dropdown* selection from the object.

This is what the current SQL query returns.

[image]

```
DECLARE @StockID int = 680

DECLARE @VariationParent int = (SELECT TOP 1 StockParent_ParentId FROM 
StockVariations SV INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = 
SV.StockParent_ChildId WHERE StockParent_ChildId = @StockID AND SV.IsDeleted = 0 
AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1) 


 SELECT DISTINCT AV.ID, AV.AttrValue, AV.AttributeTypes_Id 'AttributeTypeID', CAST(CASE WHEN SA.StockParent_Id = @StockID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BIT) 'IsDefault' 
   FROM AttributeTypes AT 
  INNER JOIN AttributeValues AV ON AV.AttributeTypes_Id = AT.Id 
  INNER JOIN StockParent_AttributeValues SA on SA.AttributeValue_Id = AV.Id 
  INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SA.StockParent_Id AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1
  WHERE SA.StockParent_Id IN (SELECT SV.StockParent_ChildId FROM StockVariations SV INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SV.StockParent_ChildId AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1 WHERE SV.StockParent_ParentId = @VariationParent AND SV.IsDeleted = 0) 
  AND SA.IsDeleted = 0 AND AT.IsDeleted = 0 AND AV.IsDeleted = 0
  ORDER BY AV.AttrValue DESC
```

I've tried to use *JQuery* code which works, but it replaces the value of the *dropdown* selection which will prevent my *Ajax* function from retrieving the correct information.

Here is the *JQuery* code which kind of works, but I want to either do this in *SQL* or *C#*. The code below will do a regex match for anything with numbers and strip out the first number and compare the size. It must be noted that sometimes the sizes in the database can have an x instead of a * separating the values.

```
<select class="variation-picker">   
    <option value="42">1500*900</option>
    <option value="48">900*900</option>
    <option value="46">2400*600</option>
    <option value="49">600*600</option>
</select>

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".variation-picker").html($(".variation-picker option").val(function () {
        return this.text.match(/\d+/);
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        var a = parseInt(a.value, 10), b = parseInt(b.value, 10);
        return a < b ? -1 : 1;
     }));

    $('.variation-picker').find('option[selected="selected"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
    });

});
```

This is the C# code I'm using in order to build the variation selection *dropdowns*. The *AttrValue* column can also contain values such as `colour` or `meters`, so it shouldn't just be tied to numeric. I don't really want to create a separate table with order priorities and etc.

```
if (ProductDetails.ProductVariations?.Count > 0)
        {
            var html = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            var colCount = 0;

            //Build the variations dropdowns

            ProductDetails.ProductVariations.ForEach(p =>
            {
                if (colCount == 2)
                {
                    colCount = 0;
                    html.AppendLine("</div>");
                    html.AppendLine("<div class='row'>");
                }

                html.AppendLine("<div class='col-md-6 single-variation-div'>");
                html.AppendLine($"<span class='text_select' id='v_{p.ID}'>{p.Name}</span><br />");
                html.AppendLine("<select class='selectpicker variation-picker' data-width='300px' onchange='javascript:ChangeProductVariance();'> ");
                p.ProdVariationValues.ForEach(v => html.AppendLine($"<option value='{v.ID}' { (v.IsDefault ? "selected='selected'" : "") }>{v.AttrValue}</option>"));
                html.AppendLine("</select><br/>");
                html.AppendLine("</div>");

                colCount++;
            });

            ProductVarienceHTML = html.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            ProductVarienceHTML = "";
        }
```

Comment: I would start working on your database first. Storing width, height and unit of measurement in one column violates the the first normal form. You should split them into three columns, height, width and unit of measurement (which you then can also put into another table and reference)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. We store the dimensions on the actual product table. We use this as a Meta tag for search parameters, groupings and etc. We use it as a grouping tag. The AttrValue can contain text like Colour and other product attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case you can't change your database schema by adding `height` and `width` columns:

Let's assume that this is your schema, just for simplifying a little your original query:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes
    ([AttrValue] varchar(13))
;

INSERT INTO attributes
    ([AttrValue])
VALUES
    ('900*900mm'),
    ('1200*900mm'),
    ('1200*1200mm')
;
```

Let's create a query that sort by the `height * width` descending:

```
SELECT
  attrValue,
  CONVERT(int, (select top 1 value from STRING_SPLIT(attrValue, '*'))) as [leftAttrValue],
  CONVERT(int, (select top 1 LEFT(value, LEN(value) - 2) from STRING_SPLIT(attrValue, '*') where value LIKE '%mm')) as [rightAttrValue]
FROM
  attributes
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(int, (select top 1 value from STRING_SPLIT(attrValue, '*'))) * 
    CONVERT(int, (select top 1 LEFT(value, LEN(value) - 2) from STRING_SPLIT(attrValue, '*') where value LIKE '%mm'))  DESC
  ;
```

The result of this query is this:

```
|   attrValue | leftAttrValue | rightAttrValue |
|-------------|---------------|----------------|
| 1200*1200mm |          1200 |           1200 |
|  1200*900mm |          1200 |            900 |
|   900*900mm |           900 |            900 |
```

You can test this in this SQL Server fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/691b3/11

So, we will adapt this now to your problem:

```
SELECT DISTINCT AV.ID, AV.AttrValue, AV.AttributeTypes_Id 'AttributeTypeID', CAST(CASE WHEN SA.StockParent_Id = @StockID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BIT) 'IsDefault' 
   FROM AttributeTypes AT 
  INNER JOIN AttributeValues AV ON AV.AttributeTypes_Id = AT.Id 
  INNER JOIN StockParent_AttributeValues SA on SA.AttributeValue_Id = AV.Id 
  INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SA.StockParent_Id AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1
  WHERE SA.StockParent_Id IN (SELECT SV.StockParent_ChildId FROM StockVariations SV INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SV.StockParent_ChildId AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1 WHERE SV.StockParent_ParentId = @VariationParent AND SV.IsDeleted = 0) 
  AND SA.IsDeleted = 0 AND AT.IsDeleted = 0 AND AV.IsDeleted = 0
  ORDER BY 
      CONVERT(int, (select top 1 value from STRING_SPLIT(AV.AttrValue, '*'))) * 
      CONVERT(int, (select top 1 LEFT(value, LEN(value) - 2) from STRING_SPLIT(AV.AttrValue, '*') where value LIKE '%mm'))  
    DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to solve it from the table structure by : adding columns with the height and the width with (INT) datatype then make order by (height * width)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution and fastest solution is doing what @Ahmad Alkaraki said.

Incase you cant then this is a solution that could work.
`SPLIT` the `AttrValue` and convert it to int, then extraxt `width` and `height`, there after extract the `size`

Have a look at `order by`

Im not sure if func `LAST` EXIST in your mssql but you get the idee

```
 SELECT DISTINCT AV.ID, AV.AttrValue, AV.AttributeTypes_Id 'AttributeTypeID', CAST(CASE WHEN SA.StockParent_Id = @StockID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as BIT) 'IsDefault',

   FROM AttributeTypes AT 
  INNER JOIN AttributeValues AV ON AV.AttributeTypes_Id = AT.Id 
  INNER JOIN StockParent_AttributeValues SA on SA.AttributeValue_Id = AV.Id 
  INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SA.StockParent_Id AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1
  WHERE SA.StockParent_Id IN (SELECT SV.StockParent_ChildId FROM StockVariations SV INNER JOIN FinGoodsParent FGP ON FGP.Id = SV.StockParent_ChildId AND FGP.IsDeleted = 0 AND FGP.Publish = 1 WHERE SV.StockParent_ParentId = @VariationParent AND SV.IsDeleted = 0) 
  AND SA.IsDeleted = 0 AND AT.IsDeleted = 0 AND AV.IsDeleted = 0
  ORDER BY ((SELECT top 1 cast(value as int) FROM STRING_SPLIT(AT.AttrValue, "*") *
            (SELECT cast(LAST(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(AT.AttrValue, "*")) DESC
```